# Помогите расширить запрос в БД

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

В проекте на Laravel 5.5 есть две таблицы:

```
Schema::create('flat_calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('flat_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->enum('status', ['booked', 'blocked', 'reserved', 'noticed']);
    $table->dateTime('start_time')->index();
    $table->dateTime('end_time')->index();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('flats', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('persons_min')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('persons_max')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Полей там больше, но я их убрал, т.к. для запроса они не нужны.

В общем, есть `flats` и календарь для них. Пользователь вводит начальную и конечную дату и число персон и запускает поиск. Необходимо вывести только те `flats`, которые не заняты (то есть для которых нет пересекающейся даты в календаре).

Вначале статусов было только два (`booked` и `blocked`) и они никак не влияли на запрос. Вот он собственно:

```
$query = Flat::with(['prices', 'photos'])
            ->where('persons_min', '<=', $persons)
            ->where('persons_max', '>=', $persons)
            ->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                $query->from('flat_calendars')
                    ->select('flat_id')
                    ->whereBetween('start_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
                    ->orWhereBetween('end_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                        $query->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                            ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);
                    });
```

SQL запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT *
FROM `flats`
WHERE `persons_min` <= '1'
    AND `persons_max` >= '1'
    AND `id` NOT IN
        (SELECT `flat_id`
        FROM `flat_calendars`
        WHERE `start_time` BETWEEN '2017-12-06 13:00:00' AND '2017-12-07 12:00:00'
        OR
        `end_time` BETWEEN '2017-12-06 13:00:00' AND '2017-12-07 12:00:00'
        OR (`start_time` <= '2017-12-06 13:00:00' AND `end_time` >= '2017-12-07 12:00:00'));
```

Запрос рабочий, все было прекрасно.
Но после добавилось еще два статуса (`reserved` и `noticed`). Теперь нужно, чтобы в результатах поиска отображались не только те `flats`, которые не пересекаются с датами в календаре, но и те, которые пересекаются, но имеют статус `reserved` или `noticed`.

Я не силен в SQL и над прошлым запросом чуть не сломал голову (но сделал), но вот теперь все же застрял.
Может кто-то сможет помочь дописать условие в запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Проблема была в скобках.
В итоге запрос такой:

```
$query = Flat::with(['prices', 'photos'])
    ->where('persons_min', '<=', $persons)
    ->where('persons_max', '>=', $persons)
    ->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
        $query->from('flat_calendars')
            ->select('flat_id')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 'booked')
                    ->orWhere('status', 'blocked');
            })
            ->where(function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                $query->whereBetween('start_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
                    ->orWhereBetween('end_time', [$start_time, $end_time])
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start_time, $end_time) {
                        $query->where('start_time', '<=', $start_time)
                            ->where('end_time', '>=', $end_time);
                    });
            });
    });
```